# Empty src folder when creating new Android Application Project in Eclipse

Tags: cordova

I am trying very hard to follow the instructions on the official [PhoneGap/Cordova getting started page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android), however when after following the steps as far as I can, I find that the **src folder** is empty (as per the example there should be files inside the src folder).

I remember trying this about 6 months earlier with earlier versions and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an Activity like in the getting started guide?

Perhaps you have any error in eclipse or so.. you can try to make a new clean installation of eclipse, eclipse-android adt plugin and android sdk.

If you have still some problems you can try adding the activity manually.

Answer (score 0):

Go to following: 
*'Help'->'Install New Software'* and type 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select ADT option and install it.
It will update the ADT.

Even I had the same problem and my issue got resolved with it!!

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).